# Jersey 2 - How to access multiple resource in a single request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

In Jersey 2, I'm trying to develop a method that allows me to pass a JSON list of couple (service, method) that representing the access path to a resource in a REST request and aggregate the result in a single response. So, the JSON list could be like this:

```
[
    {
        service : "customerService",
        method : "getCustomer",
        params : {
            id:57
        }
    },
    {
        service : "customerService",
        method : "getContacts",
        params : {
            idContact : 75
        }
    }
]
```

The corresponding command bean could be like this:

```
public class Command {

    private String method;
    private String service;

    public Command() {
    }

    public Command(final String service, final String method) {
        this.service = service;
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setMethod(final String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public void setService(final String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

And the customer service class could be like this:

```
@Path("/customerService")
public class CustomerService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getCustomer/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") final int id) {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getContacts/{idCustomer}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Contact> getContacts(@PathParam("idCustomer") final int idCustomer) {
        ...
    }   
}
```

Thus, I could make one single Ajax call to the REST and get the the contacts list and the customer data and gain an Ajax call.

My question is How dispatch command in order to execute the methods of the service. I tried to do this:

```
@Context
ExtendedResourceContext context;

@POST
@Path("/exec")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String exec(List<Command> commands) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    final List<Resource> resources = context.getResourceModel().getRootResources();

    for (final Command command : commands) {
        for (final Resource serviceResource : resources) {
            if (serviceResource.getPath().equals("/" + command.getService())) {
                System.out.println("Service found " + serviceResource.getPath());

                for (final Resource methodResource : serviceResource.getChildResources()) {
                    if (methodResource.getPath().equals("/" + command.getMethod())) {
                        for (ResourceModelComponent component : methodResource.getComponents()) {
                            if (component instanceof ResourceMethod) {
                                final ResourceMethod m = (ResourceMethod) component;
                                if (m.getHttpMethod().equals("GET") || m.getHttpMethod().equals("POST")) {
                                    final Invocable invocable = m.getInvocable();
                                    Method method = invocable.getHandlingMethod();
                                    method.invoke(this);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "ok";
}
```

But I can't instantiate some Jersey object like ExtendedResourceContext.

I've found this topic but it seems to be applied to version 1 of Jersey:
[How to access multiple resources in a single request : Jersey Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391995/how-to-access-multiple-resources-in-a-single-request-jersey-rest)

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why don't you create a new resource?.

Answer (score -1):

```
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jo1=new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray();

    jo.put("service","customerService");
    jo.put("method","getCustomer");
    jo1.put("id","57");
    jo.put("params",jo1);
    jarr.put(jo);
```

By using the above example you can resolve your problem.hope this will helpful